# Xcode 8 preprocessor Macros?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I am working with multiple targets in Xcode 8.2, Everything is good except handling files.

To import files, I have used different pch for each target but facing issues in using different class files.

How to work with other target files in the source, it throws an error on build app. When I try to add Preprocessor Macros in Build Settings but I can't find the Preprocessor Macros section in Xcode 8. Is there any alternative to this? please suggest some other approaches to handle different target files in the same source.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Select the target and go to build setting.

There search for "Preprocessor Macros" you will be able to find out. 
Set the macros for particular target.

Use #ifdef in the code to check whether macros is defined or not, based on macros definition write the code for specific target. 
That particular code will be reflected to that target only.

Comment: Yes, I know but my question was I can't find the Preprocessor Macros section in Xcode 8.2. 
Finally, I found in "All" section in Build settings. I checked in customized build settings before. 
Thanks!